# Doubly circular linked list implementation with successive update in O(1)

Tags: java, linked-list, homework, circular-list

For the queries mentioned in [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/hw4/readme.pdf) in 3 parts, the first two parts have been addressed, as mentioned below:

### Part I (6 points)

[list/DList.java](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/hw4/list/DList.java) contains a skeleton of a doubly-linked list class. Fill in the
method implementations.

*Note: "node" is passed in these methods so that user of `class DList` can avoid  slow \$O(n)\$ method to access each successive element.*

**Answer to Part I**: Filled in methods `insertFront()` `insertBack()` `front()` `back()` `next()` `prev()` `insertAfter()` `insertBefore()` `remove()` in the below code.

### Part II (1 point)

Our ADT is not as well protected as we would like. There are several ways by which a hostile (or stupid) application can corrupt our DList (i.e., make it
violate an invariant) through method calls alone.

**Answer to Part II**: Added a member `protected DList listp` in `class DListNode` to make sure that user passes the node which is actually part of the list instead of some junk node. This is one way list can be avoided from corruption. Please find `class DListNode` below.

```
/* DList.java */

package list;

/**
 *  A DList is a mutable doubly-linked list ADT.  Its implementation is
 *  circularly-linked and employs a sentinel (dummy) node at the head
 *  of the list.
 *
 *  DO NOT CHANGE ANY METHOD PROTOTYPES IN THIS FILE.
 */

public class DList {

  /**
   *  head references the sentinel node.
   *  size is the number of items in the list.  (The sentinel node does not
   *       store an item.)
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

  protected DListNode head;
  protected int size;

  /* DList invariants:
   *  1)  head != null.
   *  2)  For any DListNode x in a DList, x.next != null.
   *  3)  For any DListNode x in a DList, x.prev != null.
   *  4)  For any DListNode x in a DList, if x.next == y, then y.prev == x.
   *  5)  For any DListNode x in a DList, if x.prev == y, then y.next == x.
   *  6)  size is the number of DListNodes, NOT COUNTING the sentinel,
   *      that can be accessed from the sentinel (head) by a sequence of
   *      "next" references.
   */

  /**
   *  newNode() calls the DListNode constructor.  Use this class to allocate
   *  new DListNodes rather than calling the DListNode constructor directly.
   *  That way, only this method needs to be overridden if a subclass of DList
   *  wants to use a different kind of node.
   *  @param item the item to store in the node.
   *  @param prev the node previous to this node.
   *  @param next the node following this node.
   */
  protected DListNode newNode(Object item, DListNode prev, DListNode next, DList listp) {
    return new DListNode(item, prev, next, listp);
  }

  /**
   *  DList() constructor for an empty DList.
   */
  public DList() {
    this.head = new DListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null, null);
    this.head.next = this.head;
    this.head.prev = this.head;
    this.head.listp = this;
    this.size = 0;
  }

  /**
   *  isEmpty() returns true if this DList is empty, false otherwise.
   *  @return true if this DList is empty, false otherwise. 
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
  }

  /** 
   *  length() returns the length of this DList. 
   *  @return the length of this DList.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public int length() {
    return size;
  }

  /**
   *  insertFront() inserts an item at the front of this DList.
   *  @param item is the item to be inserted.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void insertFront(Object item) {
    this.head.next = newNode(item, this.head, this.head.next, this);
    if(this.size==0){
        this.head.prev = this.head.next;
    }else{
        this.head.next.next.prev = this.head.next;
    }
    this.size++;
  }

  /**
   *  insertBack() inserts an item at the back of this DList.
   *  @param item is the item to be inserted.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void insertBack(Object item) {
    this.head.prev = newNode(item, this.head.prev, this.head, this);
    if(this.size == 0){
        this.head.next = this.head.prev;
    }else{
        this.head.prev.prev.next = this.head.prev;
    }
    this.size++;
  }

  /**
   *  front() returns the node at the front of this DList.  If the DList is
   *  empty, return null.
   *
   *  Do NOT return the sentinel under any circumstances!
   *
   *  @return the node at the front of this DList.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public Object front() {
    if(this.size >0){
        return this.head.next.item;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  back() returns the node at the back of this DList.  If the DList is
   *  empty, return null.
   *
   *  Do NOT return the sentinel under any circumstances!
   *
   *  @return the node at the back of this DList.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public Object back() {
    if(this.size > 0){
        return this.head.prev.item;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  next() returns the node following "node" in this DList.  If "node" is
   *  null, or "node" is the last node in this DList, return null.
   *
   *  Just to make sure that passed node is part of the list that we are 
   *  working with, "listp" is added as member of "node"
   *  Do NOT return the sentinel under any circumstances!
   *
   *  @param node the node whose successor is sought.
   *  @return the node following "node".
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public DListNode next(DListNode node) {
    if((node.next != this.head) && (node.listp == this)){
        return node.next;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  prev() returns the node prior to "node" in this DList.  If "node" is
   *  null, or "node" is the first node in this DList, return null.
   *
   *  Do NOT return the sentinel under any circumstances!
   *
   *  @param node the node whose predecessor is sought.
   *  @return the node prior to "node".
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public DListNode prev(DListNode node) {
    if((node.prev != this.head) && (node.listp == this)){
        return node.prev;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  insertAfter() inserts an item in this DList immediately following "node".
   *  If "node" is null, do nothing.
   *  @param item the item to be inserted.
   *  @param node the node to insert the item after.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void insertAfter(Object item, DListNode node) {
    if((node != null) && (node.listp == this)){
        node.next = new DListNode(item, node, node.next, this);
        node.next.next.prev = node.next;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  insertBefore() inserts an item in this DList immediately before "node".
   *  If "node" is null, do nothing.
   *  @param item the item to be inserted.
   *  @param node the node to insert the item before.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void insertBefore(Object item, DListNode node) {
    if((node != null) && (node.listp == this)){
        node.prev = new DListNode(item, node.prev, node, this);
        node.prev.prev.next = node.prev;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  remove() removes "node" from this DList.  If "node" is null, do nothing.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void remove(DListNode node) {
    if((node != null) && (node.listp == this)){
        node.prev.next = node.next;
        node.next.prev = node.prev;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  toString() returns a String representation of this DList.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THIS METHOD.
   *
   *  @return a String representation of this DList.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(n) time, where n is the length of the list.
   */
  public String toString() {
    String result = "[  ";
    DListNode current = head.next;
    while (current != head) {
      result = result + current.item + "  ";
      current = current.next;
    }
    return result + "]";
  }
}
```

---

```
/* DListNode.java */

package list;

/**
 *  A DListNode is a node in a DList (doubly-linked list).
 */

public class DListNode {

  /**
   *  item references the item stored in the current node.
   *  prev references the previous node in the DList.
   *  next references the next node in the DList.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

   public Object item;
   protected DListNode prev;
   protected DListNode next;
   protected DList listp;

  /**
   *  DListNode() constructor.
   *  @param i the item to store in the node.
   *  @param p the node previous to this node.
   *  @param n the node following this node.
   */
  DListNode(Object i, DListNode p, DListNode n, DList listp) {
    this.item = i;
    this.prev = p;
    this.next = n;
    this.listp = listp;
  }
}
```

My question:

1. As part of code changes for Part I, do you think the query mentioned as Part I is addressed?
2. As part of code changes for Part II, does the observation and solution to avoid corruption of `class DList` looks correct?

Comment: Another question of yours I wish I could answer but I can't due to the "rules": I'd say that to always have a node, even for empty lists wreaks havoc upon your methods (`this.head.next.next.prev` in `insertFront`, what? How's that not a violation of Demeter's law?)... Yet I can't, because you're not allowed to alter the other methods, so sayeth your ADT concept.

Comment: What happened to the invariant "SList never returns SListNode, instead it return only an item." of your previous question? This doubly linked list does all kinds of things with nodes. That alone serves as material for a 5 paragraph answer, if not more.

Comment: @Pimgd it is returning only item despite i say `return node`, Becasue the access specifier of data members in `DListNode` are making it safe to say that only item is getting returned.

Answer (score 3):

Your `head` should be renamed `sentinel`.  It's not really the head of the list.  Rather, it's a dummy node that holds pointers to the head and the tail.

If you're going to keep track of the size of the list, do so consistently with every insertion and deletion.  You fail to update `size` in `insertAfter()`, `insertBefore()`, and `remove()`.

The advantage of using a sentinel node is that it eliminates most special cases.  For example, it makes `insertAfter()` nice and simple.  In contrast, your `insertFront()` is unnecessarily complicated.  In fact, why couldn't `insertFront()` just call `insertAfter(item, this.sentinel)`?

It's unconventional for a list node to have a `listp` pointer.  In fact, it's unconventional to expose the `DListNode` class in the interface at all.  How would a user of this class ever legitimately get their hands on a `DListNode` in the first place?

Comment: I thought of adding `listp` only after checking part 2 question. i only exposed item of `class DListNode` remaining members of `DListNdoe` are protected. so How can user tamper `DListNode` except item? otherwise how would i make sure that passed node is a genuine node that is aprt of the same list? User can pass any node to tamper the list.

Comment: Dunno. The homework assignment was invalid to begin with, in my opinion. If you cared at all about strong, non-leaky abstractions, you wouldn't expose `DListNode` in the first place. Instead, you would offer something like an [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Comment: But the assignment itself has methods that return `DListNode` and `DListNode` class is public. Despite `public class DListNode` all members are protected except `item`. So, I feel User cant corrupt list. Iterator also would traverse O(n) to access particular node, is that correct?

Comment: basically the user can't set the `listp` member and pass the node. user can only set `item`. whichever node user passed to any `DList` method has to be the one that is provided by `DList` method.

Comment: My point remains that a user can't legitimately get their hands on a `DListNode`. They aren't supposed to construct one. They could try to use `next(DListNode)` or `prev(DListNode)` to obtain one, but they would have to already have one. Perhaps you could interpret `next(null)` to mean "give me the head node, please", but the JavaDoc clearly says that you shouldn't interpret it that way. The instructor clearly hasn't thought this through before giving out this assignment.

Comment: Ya that is true, user is not suppose to construct a node. So, i will make  `public class DListNode` to `class DListNode`. Now, only `DList` can construct `DListNode`. and Do you  think it is safe to remove `listp` member as well?

Comment: Wait… _you_ screwed up! You modified the return type of `front()` and `back()`.

Comment: Only thing i can think of is, if garbage collector does not garbage the node that is removed in `remove()` method, before the user can call `remove()` passing same node. then problems can happen. So, How garbage collector works? Does it garbage the node immediately?

Comment: @overexchange no, actually the caller gets to hold on to the removed node as long as they like, and the garbage collector won't destroy it because they hold a reference. Perhaps it would make sense to modify the node in remove() to make it harmless?

Comment: @200_success For your point: *that a user can't legitimately get their hands on a DListNode*,  From outside `list` package user can't access to `DListNode` constructor.